# RegExp exercise: reluctant quantifier with a lookahead assertion

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, reluctant-quantifiers

Can you explain me how this works? Here is an example:

```
<!-- The quick brown fox 
              jumps over the lazy dog -->

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/supersheet.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!-- Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs -->
```

First, I tried to use the following regular expression to match the content inside conditional comments:

```
/<!--.*?stylesheet.*?-->/s
```

It failed, as the regular expression matches all the content before the first `<!--` and the last `-->`. Then I tried using another pattern with a lookahead assertion:

```
/<!--(?=.*?stylesheet).*?-->/s
```

It works and matches exactly what I need. However, the following regular expression works as well:

```
/<!--(?=.*stylesheet).*?-->/s
```

The last regular expression does not have a reluctant quantifier in the lookahead assertion. And now I am confused. Can anyone explain me how it works? Maybe there is a better solution for this example?

**Updated:**

I tried usig the regular expressions with lookahead assertion in another document, and it failed to mach the content between the comments. So, this one `/<!--(?=.*?stylesheet).*?-->/s` (as well as this one `/<!--(?=.*stylesheet).*?-->/s`) is not correct. Do not use it and try other suggestions.

**Updated:**

The solution has been found by **Jonny 5** (see the answer). He suggested three options:

1. Using of a negated hyphen to limit match. This option works only if there is no a hyphen between the tags. If a stylesheet has an URL `/style-sheet.css`, it will not work.
2. Using of escape sequence: `\K`. It works like a charm. The downsides are the following:

   - It is terribly slow (in my case, it was 8-10 times slower than the other solutions)
   - Only available since PHP 5.2.4
3. Using a lookahead to narrow the match. This is the goal I tried to achieve, but my expirience of using lookaround assertions was insufficient to perform the task.

I think the following is a good solution for my example:

```
/(?s)<!--(?:(?!<!).)+?stylesheet.+?-->/
```

The same but with the `s` modifier at the end:

```
/<!--(?:(?!<!).)+?stylesheet.+?-->/s
```

As I said, this is a good solution, but I managed to improve the pattern and found another one that in my case works faster.

So, the final solution is the following:

```
/<!--(?:(?!-->).)+?stylesheet.+?-->/s
```

Thanks all the participants for interesting answers.

Comment: If you want to match *<!--[if IE 7]>* before *stylesheet* could use [negated](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) hyphen: `<!--[^-]*stylesheet.*?-->` [see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aG2lZ0/1). Or put a greedy dot that eats up before and [\K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) reset after [.*\K<!--.*?stylesheet.*?-->](https://regex101.com/r/lZ5pX3/1) or use a capture group.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? I think it would be interesting for others, and for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match only the  part `<!--`...`stylesheet`...`-->` there are many ways:

1.) Use a [negated](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) hyphen `[^-]`  to limit the match and stay in between `<!--` and `stylesheet`

```
(?s)<!--[^-]+stylesheet.+?-->
```

`[^-]` allows only characters, that are not a hyphen. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aG2lZ0/2).

---

2.) To get the "last" or closest match without much regex effort, also can put a [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) before to ᗧ eat up. Makes sense if not matching globally / only one item to match. Use [\K to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) after the greed:

```
(?s)^.*\K<!--.+?stylesheet.+?-->
```

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lZ5pX3/3). Also can use a [capture group and grab $1:](https://regex101.com/r/zX8hW8/3) `(?s)^.*(<!--.+?stylesheet.+?-->)`

---

3.) Using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to narrow it down is usually more costly:

```
(?s)<!--(?:(?!<!).)+?stylesheet.+?-->
```

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dD0gI0/2). `(?!<!).` looks ahead at each character in between `<!--` and `stylesheet` if not starting another `<!`... to stay inside one element. Similar to the negated hyphen solution.

---

Instead of `.*` I used `.+` for *one or more* - depends on what to be matched. Here `+` fits better.
What solution to use depends on the exact requirements. For this case I would use the first.

Comment: @Mr.twister Welcome! I read your update - that the second solution is slower for your input. Actually this should be pretty fast. Depends on input. I did an edit and added a `^` start [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to second solution for avoiding unnecessary backtracking. For Many cases the lookahead solution would be slower. Your modification to `(?!-->).` is fine - more specific.

Answer (score 2):

The string `stylesheet` is mentioned only one time in your test document, so both regular expressions you tried will match the same thing but in different ways.

```
<!--(?=.*?stylesheet).*?-->/s
```

This one does the following:

- Capture `<!--`.
- Look ahead, capturing characters up to and including `stylesheet`. Fail if not found.
- Capture characters up to and including `-->`.

```
<!--(?=.*stylesheet).*?-->/s
```

This one does the following:

- Capture `<!--`.
- Look ahead, capturing any character until no longer possible. Backtrack, continuously trying to match `stylesheet`. Fail if not found.
- Capture characters up to and including `-->`.

Basically, one needs to backtrack significantly while the other doesn't.

If your subject instead is...

```
<!-- The quick brown fox 
              jumps over the lazy dog -->

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/supersheet.css" /> <![endif]-->

<!-- Pack my box with five dozen stylesheets -->
```

you get two different results. The former would find the first `stylesheet`, while the latter would find the second (and last) since it starts searching from the end of the string.

Comment: Very interesting answer! Thank you, @Anonymous! The solution has been found. Please, see the updated post.